# How prove the differential equation about limit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

function x(t) on [0, ∞) is satisfied with next differential equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} =( -a + b(t))\:x + c(t) \\
\end{equation}

Additionaly, **a** is defined positive constant.

And then , if continuous function b(t), c(t) is satisfied with below,

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \infty} b(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty } c(t) = 0
\end{equation}

Please prove that next equality is satisfied 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Multiply the equation by $e^{\int_{0}^{t}(a-b(s))ds}$. Solve the equation, and compute the limit. Apply L'Hospital in the case that $\int_{0}^{u} (e^{\int_{0}^{t}(a-b(s))ds}c(t))dt\to\infty$ as $u\to\infty$.

Comment: @user565560 i know l'hospital , but i don't understand this case . Could you be more specific ∫u0(e∫t0(a−b(s))dsc(t))dt→∞  as u→ ∞ ?  sorry...